# Reshaping a dataframe based on lag features, such that the lag features are now rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
size    price   target  size_lag_2  size_lag_1  price_lag_2 price_lag_1
0   1   1.1 5   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2   2.2 6   NaN 1.0 NaN 1.1
2   3   3.3 7   1.0 2.0 1.1 2.2
3   4   4.4 8   2.0 3.0 2.2 3.3
```

Not sure if there is a better way to display the dataframe on here?

Each row is a sample with a target I will be trying to predict. I want each sample to be it's own dataframe for now such that there are only 2 feature columns, size and price. This is time series data, so the first row should be size_lag_2 and price_lag_2 as those are the first time steps(I will remove the Nan rows). Next row is size_lag_1 and last row is size.

The final output should be a list of dataframes, 1 dataframe per row. As well as a list of the targets that align to each dataframe. My actual problem has more features and more lags, so I will need a function that can do this on n features and n lags.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: post final dataframes for the first 2 rows